# 2-cycles and limits

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I was just wondering. If a sequence $x_n$ has an attracting two cycle, we say that it tends to the 2-cycle a,b. Now, my question is, during some exercises in mathcad, the sequences actually seem to end up in the two cycle after a certain point. For example, when iterating the function $x^2 - 1$ with the start term $x_0=-\frac{1}{2}$ , it seemed like after a certain point the sequence just alternated between 0 and -1.

Now, is this because of rounding in mathcad? If not, isn't in-correct to say it **tends to** the 2-cycle? When it actually ends up becoming the 2-cycle.

(Note: It would make perfect sense to me that the sequence just went back and forward between the two numbers if i had started on one of them, but it seems like most sequences I look at in mathcad ends alternating between the two points of the two cycle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of rounding.  If you have $x_n=a$, with $a \lt 0$ and $|a| \ll 1$, then $x_{n+1}=a^2-1$, and $x_{n+2}=a^4-2a^2\approx -2a^2$.  These are not exactly $0$ and $-1$, but are closer than $x_n$ is to zero.  Every two iterations the number of accurate decimal points doubles.  Mathematically, it is never equal to $0, -1$.  You quickly (in Excel, in 17 or so iterations) get close enough that it only chooses to display $0$ and $-1$.  The computer math in Excel makes it exactly $0$ and $-1$, but I believe Mathcad will use arbitrary precision.  Try adding $1$ to the ones close to $-1$ and see what you get.  In Excel after 15 iterations it is displaying $-1$ with no decimals, but when I add $1$ I get $1.33E-12$ so the computer still knows it is not exactly $-1$

Comment: Thank you! I suspected that this was the case. All the way though the chapter I had though of the cycle as limits. The mathcad exercises just managed to make me doubt my understanding :D I did suspect that it was because of rounding, but I wanted to confirm, otherwise, I would have had to revise more since my understand would have been wrong. Again, thanks for clearing this up :)